# SQL - map rows based on date window and condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888758/sql-map-rows-based-on-dates) and now trying to handle an edge case that came up. In the original problem, the dates worked out nicely in that associated cases had matching `open_date`/`close_date` pairs. But in the example below, case4 and case3 are supposed to be linked but case3 closed after case4 opened. We are able to tell that these two cases should be linked because case3 cannot be a final case in a sequence because it has the status `deferred` and its `close_date` is in close proximity to when the next deferred case was opened. I'm wondering if there is a good way to consider this condition when matching the cases by `open_date`/`close_date`?

```
case_id open_date  close_date  user_id type     status      
case5   2021-06-01 2021-08-25  user1   request  complete
case4   2021-05-05 2021-06-01  user1   request  deferred
case3   2021-03-01 2021-05-12  user1   request  deferred
case2   2020-09-15 2021-03-01  user1   request  deferred
case1   2020-09-01 2020-09-15  user1   request  deferred
```

Yet another edge case that came up is something like the following where two cases are linked but do not have matching `open_date`/`close_date` but they were opened in close succession to one another.

```
case_id open_date  close_date  user_id type     status      
case3   2022-01-20 null        user1   request  pending
case2   2021-10-04 2022-01-20  user1   request  deferred
case1   2021-10-03 2021-12-12  user1   request  deferred
```

Comment: Your data looks like it contains a mistake, where case2 contains an open date after the close date.  I think you meant to have a close date of 2021 for case2.  The answer is simple.  Your original answer actually handles the "edge" case.  This is an overlapping case.  I'll show the answer with MySQL.  It's in the same form.  I added the COALESCE which I think you also have, but didn't show.

Comment: Yes you are right! Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make a small adjustment to your `BigQuery` code on the inner `FROM` statement:

```
with your_table as ( 
  select 'case5' as case_id, '2021-06-01' as open_date, '2021-08-25' as close_date, 'user1' as user_id, 'request' as type union all
  select 'case4', '2021-05-05', '2021-06-01', 'user1', 'request' union all
  select 'case3', '2021-03-01', '2021-05-12', 'user1', 'request' union all
  select 'case2', '2020-09-15', '2021-03-01', 'user1', 'request' union all 
  select 'case1', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-15', 'user1', 'request' 
)
select *, 
  case row_number() over(partition by user_id, type, map_id order by open_date) 
    when 1 then 'new case'
    when count(1) over(partition by user_id, type, map_id) then 'last deferred case'
    else 'deferred case'
  end as status
from (
  select * except(new_case), 
    countif(new_case) over(partition by user_id, type order by open_date) as map_id 
  from (
    select *, 
      case when open_date <=  lead(close_date) over(partition by user_id, type order by open_date desc) then false
           when open_date != lead(close_date) over(partition by user_id, type order by open_date desc) then true
           else False end new_case
    from your_table
  )
)
```

I have tested with old scenario and new scenario and a combined one. This should address your issue. I consult the following documentation for it:

- [Conditional expressions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions)

Comment: Hello `trololo` , have you managed to make it work?

Comment: Your answer worked! Thank you!! It actually handles another edge case which I will add above.

Comment: I'm glad to know it worked. Please also, upvote if this answer was useful.

Comment: Ah yes for sure done!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just a tiny adjustment (based on the original solution provided by @MikhailBerlyant) to allow / detect overlap of successive cases.

[The fiddle (with original and new problem)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ad210b7b55a677e1f32313e87eb2a3c)

Notice the inequality: `open_date > lead(close_date)`

```
with your_table (case_id, open_date, close_date, user_id, type) as (
  select 'case5', '2021-06-01', '2021-08-25', 'user1', 'request' union all
  select 'case4', '2021-05-05', '2021-06-01', 'user1', 'request' union all
  select 'case3', '2021-03-01', '2021-05-12', 'user1', 'request' union all
  select 'case2', '2020-09-15', '2021-03-01', 'user1', 'request' union all 
  select 'case1', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-15', 'user1', 'request' 
)
select *, 
  case row_number() over(partition by user_id, type, map_id order by open_date) 
    when 1 then 'new case'
    when count(1) over(partition by user_id, type, map_id) then 'last deferred case'
    else 'deferred case'
  end as status
from (
  select *, 
    SUM(new_case) over(partition by user_id, type order by open_date) as map_id
  from (
    select *, 
      COALESCE(open_date > lead(close_date) over(partition by user_id, type order by open_date desc), 1) new_case
    from your_table
  ) AS t1
) AS t2
ORDER BY open_date DESC
;
```

The result:

| case_id | open_date | close_date | user_id | type | new_case | map_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| case5 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-08-25 | user1 | request | 0 | 1 | last deferred case |
| case4 | 2021-05-05 | 2021-06-01 | user1 | request | 0 | 1 | deferred case |
| case3 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-05-12 | user1 | request | 0 | 1 | deferred case |
| case2 | 2020-09-15 | 2021-03-01 | user1 | request | 0 | 1 | deferred case |
| case1 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-15 | user1 | request | 1 | 1 | new case |